# CGAffineTransform on OpenGL view and its affect on view size

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

I am debugging an issue in which a library I am using creates an OpenGL view, and triggers a memory warning.

One thing I noticed is that setting the view to a fraction of the window size causes it to work fine.  When debugging via the view via XCodes interface debugger I see that the bounds of the view go well out past the bounds of the parent view.  When printing the view in question I see this:

```
<RenderView: 0x140a61d10; frame = (5 0; 1019 728); transform = [1019, 0, 0, 728, 0, 0]; layer = <CALayer: 0x140ad0a40>>
```

I am unfamiliar with this, but from reading the [CGAffineTransform docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/#//apple_ref/c/macro/CGAffineTransformMake%20) it seems that the variables being set are "a" and "d" which correspond to the scale sx and sy.

So my question is would this transform actually be displaying a view which is 1019*1019 x 728*728, does this seem suspicious?  likely a bug in the library, or is my understand incorrect?

I am seeing this issue using Xcode 7, on multiple devices, currently testing on a iPad Pro 9.7 running 9.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's clarification on what goes where between a 2x3 CGAffineTransform and a GLKMatrix4...

Your CGAffineTransform that represents the preferred or actual transform of your view or asset dimensions and orientation (or aspect) translate to a GLKMatrix4 (or mat4, which is multiples against the position in your vertex shader), thusly:

```
CGAffineTransform preferredTransform= [videoTrack preferredTransform];

GLfloat preferredTransformMatrix[] = {
preferredTransform.a, preferredTransform.b, preferredTransform.tx, 0.0,
preferredTransform.c, preferredTransform.d, preferredTransform.ty, 0.0,
0.0,                  0.0,                  1.0,                   0.0,
0.0,                  0.0,                  0.0,                   1.0
};
```

This is just an example showing the correct positions for each value in a 2x3 Matrix for a 4x4 matrix.